# Blazor WebAssembly Azure B2C Error: AADB2C90205 (insufficient permissions)

Tags: azure, blazor, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly

I created a sample Blazor WebAssembly app to be secured with Azure B2C using the steps outlined in the Microsoft docs article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-3.1.

The application works except for the authentication.  The B2C modal loads to sign-in, but then the UI displays the following error message.

`There was an error trying to log you in: 'AADB2C90205: This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation.`

Here are some redacted screenshots for my B2C configuration (I'm sure the code is correct as it's the default code generated from the `dotnet new` CLI command).

Any ideas on the configuration error?

**App Registrations**
[image: App Registrations]

**API - Overview**
[image: API - Overview]

**API - Authentication**
[image: API - Authentication]

**API - Expose an API**
[image: API - Expose an API]

**Client - Overview**
[image: Client - Overview]

**Client - Authentication**
[image: Client - Authentication]

**Client - API Permissions**
[image: Client - API Permissions]

**Sign-up/in User Flow - Overview**
[image: Sign-up/in User Flow - Overview]

**Sign-up/in User Flow - User Attributes**
[image: Sign-up/in User Flow - User Attributes]

**Sign-up/in User Flow - Application Claims**
[image: Sign-up/in User Flow - Application Claims]

Comment: Can you please share us the B2c url?Also, please mask the clientid/secrets with stars(**) as it is public channel

Comment: Thanks @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity, I've updated the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the issue was actually in the code.

I missed a note section in the docs that said I had to manually edit the client app code if API ID URI was *untrusted publisher domain similar to https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/41451fa7-82d9-4673-8fa5-69eff5a761fd*, which it was in my case.

Removing the extra `https://{TENANT DOMAIN}/` in the `Program.cs` of the client app fixed things (note the difference between the commented-out line and the line that comes after).

```
namespace BlazorClient
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            ...

            builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
                //options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://***.onmicrosoft.com/https://***.onmicrosoft.com/*******/blazor.client");
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://***.onmicrosoft.com/*******/blazor.client");
            });

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem. The reason for the error is that you have used unauthorized resources. You need to change the `scope` to your own expose api. Go to Azure AD B2C>App registrations>your client application>API permissions.

[image]

[image]